# How to make my vine video with sound not muted at the start

Tags: video, vine

Is there a way in my script to unmute the video? i always need to click the sound button to have the sound:
iframe class="vine-embed" src="https://vine.co/v//embed/simple" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"script async src="//platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js" charset="utf-8"

Or can i make my own embed.js and make sound to come out at same time as the video and point it at my domain instead of vine?

Thank's for your infos

Answer (score 1):

Use Below  "audio=1"

```
<iframe class="vine-embed" src="https://vine.co/v/h0xHmmx1nZH/embed/simple?audio=1" 
width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe><script async 
src="//platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```